# Iterating a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm having trouble correctly iterating a multi-dimension array I am trying to retrieve the values for each well..value.

My Issue is I seem to have an array within an array which has an array for each key/pair value, I'm unsure how to loop through these and add the values to the database for each array.

Eg, if I have one form on my page the array return is **below** and further below that is what is returned with two forms etc

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
             (
                [name] => sl_propid
                [value] => 21
             )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_date
                [value] => 04/01/2014
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_ref
                [value] => Form1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_nom_id
                [value] => 12
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_desc
                [value] => Form1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_vat
                [value] => 60
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [name] => sl_net
                [value] => 999
            )

    )

)
```

---

[image: More than one form]

---

**My question is how do I iterate through the returned array no matter it's size and pull back each value**?

I have tried **nesting foreach loops**, which did give me results, but only for one key/value pair which leads me to believe I'm doing the looping wrong, I can retrieve the values if I statically access them, which is of course no use normally.

```
foreach ($result as $array) {
            print_r($array);

    }
```

the above foreach returns the above arrays, adding another foreach removes the out "container" array but adding another foreach loop, returns only one key/value pair, which sort makes sense because the first index is an array, too, hope I haven't confused everyone else as much as already have myself D:.

Thank you for reading
Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT Using the below array walk recursive I get the output

```
    $result = $this->input->post();


    function test_print($item, $key)
    {
    echo "$key holds $item\n";


    //$this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($key, $key, $key, $key, $key, $key, $key);
    }

        array_walk_recursive($result, 'test_print');


    }
```

[image: Returns this]

Which is almost what I want but how do I take each individual value and add it to my ModelFunction (to actually input the data to DB)

The function takes 7 parameters but I am unsure how to make sure the right info goes to the correct parameter

```
$this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($propid, $date, $ref, $nomid, $desc, $vat, $net);
```

---

My Controller function

```
function addInvoiceToLedger(){
         $this->load->model('SalesLedgerModel');
         // $propid = $this->input->post('propid');

     // $date = $this->input->post('date');
     // $ref = $this->input->post('ref');
     // $nomid = $this->input->post('id');
     // $desc = $this->input->post('desc');
     // $vat = $this->input->post('vat');
     // $net = $this->input->post('sl_net');



    $results = $this->input->post();
    //var_dump($results);   

        $size1 = sizeof($results)-1;

        for($i=0; $i<=$size1; $i++)
        {
            $size2 = sizeof($results[$i])-1;

            for($j=0; $j<=$size2; $j++)
            {
                $name = $results[$i][$j]['name'];
                $value = $results[$i][$j]['value'];

               echo $value . "\n" ; 
               $this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($value, $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, $value);

            }
        }
```

My Model function

```
function addInvoiceToLedger($propid, $date, $ref, $nomid, $desc, $vat, $net){

        $data = array('sl_prop_id' => $propid, 'sl_date' => $date,
            'sl_ref' => $ref, 'sl_nominal_sub' => $nomid, 'sl_invoice_desc' => $desc, 'sl_vat' => $vat, 'sl_amount' => $net);

        $this->db->insert('salesledger', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It'll be much faster. Since 3 `foreach loops` is much costlier than 2 `for loops` (`for loops` are faster than `foreach loops`) -

```
$size1 = sizeof($results)-1;

if($size1 > 0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<=$size1; $i++)
    {
        $size2 = sizeof($results[$i])-1;

        if($size2 > 0)
        {
            for($j=0; $j<=$size2; $j++)
            {
                $name = $results[$i][$j]['name'];
                $value = $results[$i][$j]['value'];

                $insert = $this->your_model->insert($name, $value);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It throws errors for undefined offset [0] :( `Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: controllers/FinancialInput.php`

On line 49 which is      `$size2 = sizeof($results[$i]);`

Comment: I just tested. Its working fine. This might come when the array is empty.

Comment: No you are correct, it does work, that is, I can print out each value but I still don't understand how I can pass this to my model function :( (which is in question) if I try pass it $value then it will simply put the first value in every column, same problem as I had with answer below D:

Comment: The "query" bit is no use to me as this is in my controller not my model, I'm just trying pass the right variables to the right parameters

Comment: Check edited one. I guess this is what you are talking about.

Comment: Not quite since the model function takes 7 parameters all at once to add one complete record, thank you for your time but I think this is too difficult for me to work out.

Comment: Can i see your model function?

Comment: `$this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($propid, $date, $ref, $nomid, $desc, $vat, $net);` is the function and all the values I need are within the array. I will post my full controller and Model In the original post though in case you need to see something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write some recursive code to step through the array and call itself again if an element turns into an array, or write a very simple function and call it via [array walk recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) which will then let you do whatever you like with the value:

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Output:

```
a holds apple
b holds banana
sour holds lemon
```

Comment: I am unsure how to use the values in my model function `$this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($propid, $date, $ref, $nomid, $desc, $vat, $net);` because I couldn't just set it to `$this->SalesLedgerModel->addInvoiceToLedger($item, $item, $item, $item, $item, $item, $item);` as the variable would keep changing, or am I understand wrong again?

Comment: Or would I use the key?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry. You should be passing the params to the function as needed?

Comment: Sorry I seem to annoy people on here with lack of ability to explain, as you can see my AddInVoiceToLedger method takes 7 parameters, for each time it inserts a new db entry. How do I get  the values from the test_print function into my AddInVoiceToLedger function, in the right order? For example I couldn't say $propid = $key because then the loop would overwrite propid multiple times for everytime the key changes, am I making any sense? D:

This is so frustrating I can't even explain properly what I'm trying to do nevermind figure it myself haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $array) {
  foreach($array as $arr){
     foreach($arr as $a){
       echo $a[value];
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: This won't work for an array nested in the second array.